# How to filter values where there is string values in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I've df as:

```
   Numbers   String   AlphaNumString
0   123       sea       sea123
1   456       sky       sky456
3   456'      sky1      nuts
4   Nan       tea3      45tea
5   562       656       L2.36
6   896       light     5642
7   s456      Nan       Nan
8   963       lf56      pe562
9   456%      per       per789
10  Nan       456       123k
```

output: df1
filter out rows that contain pure numeric values or `Nan` in the `Numbers` column.

```
   Numbers   String   AlphaNumString
0   123       sea       sea123
1   456       sky       sky456
2   Nan       tea3      45tea
3   562       656       L2.36
4   896       light     5642
5   963       lf56      pe562
6   Nan       456       123k
```

Comment: I'd be easier to help if you post your code and the problem that you have faced

Comment: df[~df.Numbers.str.contains(r'[a-zA-Z]')] i was using this code but problem is, this code excludes Nan and also retains string value like 456'.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regular expressions.

Run just `df[df.Numbers.isna() | df.Numbers.str.isnumeric()]`, i.e. select rows
where *Numbers* column:

- either is *NaN*,
- or the content is convertible to a number.

But if you want to "limit" allowed numeric values to just integers,
change this expression to:

```
df[df.Numbers.isna() | df.Numbers.str.isdigit()]
```

Comment: I believe isdigit() function won't work for float datatype.

Comment: For *float* data type it will not work. But this column contains also letters, so it is od *object* type. Actually, more general solution would be to check the columns type as the first step. If the type is *float* then all rows should be returned.